# How to add this old BASIC code snippet to work in Arduino C++ for FastLED?

Tags: arduino-ide, c++, led, arduino-leonardo, rgb-led

I've been trying to implement this old code that randomly transitions to RGB color into my Arduino board that uses FastLED.

```
Static Col1, Col2, Col3 As Integer
Static C1, C2, C3 As Integer
If (Col1 = 0 Or Col1 = 250) And (Col2 = 0 Or Col2 = 250) And (Col3 = 0 Or Col3 = 250) Then
  C1 = Int(Rnd * 3)
  C2 = Int(Rnd * 3)
  C3 = Int(Rnd * 3)
End If
If C1 = 1 And Col1 <> 0 Then Col1 = Col1 - 10
If C2 = 1 And Col2 <> 0 Then Col2 = Col2 - 10
If C3 = 1 And Col3 <> 0 Then Col3 = Col3 - 10
If C1 = 2 And Col1 <> 250 Then Col1 = Col1 + 10
If C2 = 2 And Col2 <> 250 Then Col2 = Col2 + 10
If C3 = 2 And Col3 <> 250 Then Col3 = Col3 + 10
leds[x] = RGB(Col1, Col2, Col3)
```

Here is my Arduino setup:

```
#include <FastLED.h>

#define LED_COUNT 60
#define LED_OUT       13
#define BUTTON_IN     10
#define ANALOG_INPUT  A9
#define EXTRA_PIN_A    7
#define EXTRA_PIN_B   11

struct CRGB leds[LED_COUNT];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  LEDS.addLeds<WS2812B, LED_OUT, GRB>(leds, LED_COUNT);
  LEDS.show();
}

void loop() {
  //where to implement 
}
```

Comment: To be continued ... https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/43485/leds-randomly-smooth-transitioning-accounting-for-black-or-how-to-switch-using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work fine:

```
#include <FastLED.h>

#define LED_COUNT     96
#define LED_OUT       13
#define BUTTON_IN     10
#define ANALOG_INPUT  A9
#define EXTRA_PIN_A    7
#define EXTRA_PIN_B   11

struct CRGB leds[LED_COUNT];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  LEDS.addLeds<WS2812B, LED_OUT, GRB>(leds, LED_COUNT);
  LEDS.show();
}

void colorLoop() {  

  static int Col1;
  static int Col2;
  static int Col3;

  static int C1;
  static int C2;
  static int C3;

if ((((Col1 == 0) || (Col1 == 250)) && (((Col2 == 0) || (Col2 == 250)) && ((Col3 == 0) || (Col3 == 250))))) {

// select a random number from 1 to 2 for the array
C1 = random(1, 3);
C2 = random(1, 3);
C3 = random(1, 3);
}

if (((C1 == 1) && (Col1 != 0))) {
    Col1 = (Col1 - 10);
}
if (((C2 == 1) && (Col2 != 0))) {
    Col2 = (Col2 - 10);
}
if (((C3 == 1) && (Col3 != 0))) {
    Col3 = (Col3 - 10);
}


if (((C1 == 2) && (Col1 != 250))) {
    Col1 = (Col1 + 10);
}
if (((C2 == 2) && (Col2 != 250))) {
    Col2 = (Col2 + 10);
}
if (((C3 == 2) && (Col3 != 250))) {
    Col3 = (Col3 + 10);
}

for (uint8_t i = 0; i < LED_COUNT; i++) {
   leds[i] = CRGB(Col1, Col2, Col3);
  }
delay(100);
LEDS.show();
}

void loop() {
  colorLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fairly simple. Understand what the basic code is trying to do and recreate that functionality in c.

In this case, it is looking for a set of conditions to trigger the generation of three random numbers which are then combined into a code for the run array.